# how do I match the boolean values coming from the external method in karate feature file

Tags: karate

I've written some method in java that returns true or false.
 In the karate feature how should I match?

This is how I am matching

```
* def ValidationOfVertex = """ function(args1,args2,args3) {
  var CustomFunctions = Java.type('com.optum.graphplatform.RegressionTest');
  var cf = new CustomFunctions();
  return cf.ValidationOfVertex(args1,args2,args3);
}"""
* def result = call ValidationOfVertex(vertexUrl,"BillType",token1) 
#And match response contains 'true'
```

I am getting below error

> actual: null, expected: 'true', reason: actual is not a string

Comment: Seems that you defined `result` but check `response`

Comment: tried that one also getting error like  actual is null and expected is true

Comment: @barbsan any other way to match boolean values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of `call` is wrong. Read the docs. If you are not interested in reading the docs, then forget about `call` and use JS directly like this:

```
* def result = ValidationOfVertex(vertexUrl,"BillType",token1)
* match result == true
```

Comment: Thank you ,will read the doc how we can call the functions in karate fetaures